# Lagrange Equation for a physical pendulum attached to a spring

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, oscillators

I have a very specific problem and need a lagrangian equation and differential equation for the motion of mass $m$.

The center of a metal rod with length $2R$ is attached to a ball bearing so it can rotate freely. The metal rod has mass $M$ and another weight with mass $m$ is attached to one end of the rod. The other end is connected to a spring with constant $d$.

First, the mass is deflected by $\varphi$ degrees and then let off. This should create a damped harmonic oscillation.

How would you describe this setup with Lagrangian Mechanics?

[image]

Comment: I'd do it by first writing out the coordinates. Then I'd define the kinetic & potential energies using those coordinates. Lastly, I'd solve the Euler-Lagrange equations. Which part of that process are you having difficulty on?

Comment: I’m having difficulty on finding the right expressions for the kinetic and potential energy. My first take was:

Comment: $U= \frac{1}{2} m R^2 \dot{\varphi} + \frac{1}{2} \Theta \varphi^2$ where $\Theta$ is the moment of inertia of the rod and $V= -m g R sin(\varphi) + \frac{1}{2} d R^2 sin(\varphi)^2$

Comment: With $x= R cos(\varphi), \quad \dot{x}=-Rsin(\varphi) \dot{\varphi} \quad$ and $y=R sin(\varphi) ,\quad \dot{y}=R cos(\varphi) \dot{\varphi} $